# How static inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class can Avoid Android Memory Leaks? Need an example

Tags: android, memory-leaks, static, inner-classes, weak-references

I was studying this article, [Avoid Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). There are few suggestions to avoid memory leaks, one of them is below:

> Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control
> their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference
> to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a static
> inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done in
> ViewRoot and its W inner class for instance

1- Can some one elaborate this by giving an example?

2- How to use to static inner classes with Weak-reference to the inner classes?

3- what are the best practices to use that static class in your application to Avoid Memory leaks.

Great thanks.

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002350/android-weak-reference-of-inner-class ?

Comment: Thanks. yes i have seen it, but i still need a simple example with explination.

Answer (score 1):

In this post, an answer shows a simple example of what you are looking for:
[How to instantiate interface in fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623468/how-to-instantiate-interface-in-fragment)

BUT, one problem is that sometimes a Fragment lives longer than its Activity, for example, if the Activity has a config change (e.g. rotated) then the Activity is destroyed, but the Fragment can be kept alive and then reattached to the new (rotated) Activity. See this post: 
[Android Fragment lifecycle over orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474104/android-fragment-lifecycle-over-orientation-changes)

So you might have a problem with the proposed solution using the WeakReference, because after a rotation you would have a reference to the old Activity (or maybe nothing).

What seems to work for me:

1)  When I need a ref to the Activity, call getActivity(). Can do this right in onPostExecute() of a member AsyncTask class, for example.

2)  Check the result for null (this can happen: Fragments can live longer than their Activities)

3)  Check if activity isFinishing() – you don’t want to do certain UI things in that state.

4)  Cast activity to your interface type.

5)  Call callback in interface type.